# How to remove pm/am from smart gwt calendar

Tags: java, gwt, calendar, smartgwt

I made a calendar with smart GWT. Disabled both Day/Week tab and set the default to Month. I want to remove the am/pm time from the calendar. I don't need am/pm time because I'm using day as the smallest time unit.

Is there are any way to remove it? I was able to alter it by using:

```
calendar.setTimeFormatter(TimeDisplayFormat.TO24HOURTIME);
```

but there is no option to disable it, only to alter it.

Is this possible at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use:

```
calendar.setTimeFormatter(TimeFormatter.TOSHORT24HOURTIME);
```

**Edit:**

What you want is not supported in the current formatter enum, but I think you can create some workaround (haven't try that although but give it a try).

1. edit the Calendar.js and change it to something like this (see [here](http://code.google.com/p/smartgwt/issues/detail?id=460)):

   ```
   formatCellValue : function (value, record, rowNum, colNum, grid) {
        return "";
   }
   ```
2. Create a copy of you new formatter, that is very like NativeTimeDisplayFormatter (it's final so you can't exteds it), and in the format method return you date format (in JS).
   then overload the setTimeFormatter so you'll be able to get your formatter, and do the same functionallity like the original one.

Comment: Well it just change it to 00:00 format. I want to remove it completely.

Comment: Yap, no nice way to do it, but I was happy to help. what option did you try btw?

Comment: I editted the JS file. var _14 = "<a href='javascript:" + this.ID + ".monthViewEventClick(" + _4 + "," + _5 + "," + i + ");' class='" + this.calMonthEventLinkStyle + "'>";
                _11 += _14 + _13 + _7[i][this.nameField] + "</a><br/>" I commented the '_14 + _13 +' out.